# Powerpoint ExportAsFixedFormat - Hide "Publishing..." progress dialog

Tags: c#, .net, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

I've written a class that converts documents in powerpoint format to a pdf document with the help of interop methods from Office14.
Everything works fine and I get exactly the result I want.

The problem I have is the dialog that pops up when calling the method:

```
PowerPoint.Presentation.ExportAsFixedFormat
```

The dialog displays the export progress, has the title "Publishing..." and a Cancel button. (Cannot use images in my posts yet...)

I am wondering if there is any way to hide this dialog during the export process.

I've already tried the following approaches but without any success:

```
PowerPoint.Application app = new PowerPoint.Application();
app.DisplayDocumentInformationPanel = false;      
app.DisplayAlerts = PowerPoint.PpAlertLevel.ppAlertsNone;
```

Thanks for your help.

Best Regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 0):

I also tried making the application invisible, but that didn't seem to help as well.

Don't have an answer for your question, but wanted to propose another way of doing it. How about installing a virtual pdf printer and printing the presentation? This has drawbacks as well, but it may solve your issue (depending on your requirements).